# Payroll program in C++

Tags: c++

I have been working on this program for a class, however I cannot get my output correct.

My instructions from the assignment are:

> Expand the Employee Payroll program to include hourly based and salary based employees. This phase uses an array of employee objects, inheritance for different classes of employees, and polymorphism for salary computation. The 52 week yearly salary as well as number of overtime hours worked by a salary based employee is given).
>
> For salary based employees, to find the regular (gross) pay for a week, divide the salary by 52. To compute the overtime pay for a salary based employee, first find the hourly rate by dividing the gross pay by 40, and then compute overtime pay. For every employee, overtime pay, tax amount, and net pay must also be computed.
>
> In addition, the program should find the minimum and maximum net pay of all employees as well as sort the employees based on their net pay (ascending order)

And this is what I have so far:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int totalEmployeeCount,hrs,employeeCounter,stat,empID;
double rate,regPay;
string fName;
string lName;

class employee{
public:
double salary,hourlyRate,taxRate,taxAmount,grossPay,netPay,otPay;
int hours,otHours;

public: void setVariables(int empID,string fName,string lName, int stat, 
double rate, double hrs){
    int employeeID = empID;
    string firstName = fName;
    string lastName = lName;
    int payStat = stat;
    if(payStat ==1){hourlyRate = rate;}
    else{salary = rate;}
    hours = hrs;
}
//DECLARE FUNCTION TO CALCULATE GROSS PAY
public: virtual double calculateGrossPay()=0;

double calculateTaxAmount(){ taxRate = .30; // tax rate is a flat rate of 30%
taxAmount = grossPay*taxRate;  // CALCULATE TAX AMOUNT
return taxAmount;
}       // END CALCULATE TAXAMOUNT() FUNCTION.

double calculateNetPay(){
    netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
    return netPay;
}       // END CALCULATENETPAY() FUNCTION.
void printData(){
    cout<<setprecision(2)<<setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);
    cout<<fName<<setw(6)<<lName<<setw(6)<<empID<<setw(10)<<hrs<<setw(3)
    <<otHours<<setw(8)<<grossPay<<setw(8)<<netPay<<setw(8)<<otPay<<endl;}  
// END PRINTDATA() FUNCTION
}; // END EMPLOYEE CLASS

class employeeSalary : public employee{
    public: double calculateGrossPay() { 
    double regPay = hours*hourlyRate;
    double hourlyRate = ((salary/52)/40);
    if (hours > 40) {otHours = (hours - 40); //calculate OT hours
     otPay = (otHours * hourlyRate); //calculate OT pay
     grossPay = (regPay + otPay); }
    else if (hours <= 40) {otHours = 0; otPay = 0; grossPay = regPay;}
    return grossPay;    } 
}; //end EmployeeSalary class 

class employeeHourly : public employee{
  public: double calculateGrossPay(){ 
   regPay = (40 * hourlyRate); //calculate regular hours
  if (hours > 40){   otHours = (hours - 40); //calculate OT hours
     otPay = (otHours * hourlyRate * 1.5); //calculate OT pay
     grossPay = (regPay + otPay); //calculate gross pay
  } //enf if clause for gross pay with overtime
  else { otHours = 0;   otPay = 0; grossPay = regPay;
  } //end else clause for four hours
  return grossPay;  } //end calculateGrossPay() function
}; //end EmployeeHourly class

int main(){
int employeeCounter;
cout<< "enter # of employees you want to process:  ";
cin>>totalEmployeeCount;
employee*employee[100];
while(employeeCounter < totalEmployeeCount){
    cout<<"Is employee "<<employeeCounter+1<< " hourly or salary? (enter 1 
for hourly / 2 for salary):";
    cin>>stat;
    if (stat == 1){cout<< "Instantiating and HOURLY employee object 
inherited from base class employee"
    <<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";
        cin>>empID;
        cout<<"Enter employee's first name: "; 
         cin>>fName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's last name: ";
         cin>>lName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hourly wage: "; 
         cin>>rate;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hours for this week: "; 
         cin>>hrs;
        employee[employeeCounter] = new employeeHourly();         
        employee[employeeCounter]->setVariables(empID, fName, lName, stat, 
rate, hrs);
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateGrossPay(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateTaxAmount(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateNetPay();
        cout<<endl<<endl;
            employeeCounter++; } //end if
     
    else{cout<<"instantialting a SALARY employee object in herited from base class employee"
    <<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";
        cin>>empID;
        cout<<"Enter employee's first name: "; 
         cin>>fName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's last name: ";
         cin>>lName;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hourly wage: "; 
         cin>>rate;
        cout<<"Enter employee's hours for this week: "; 
         cin>>hrs;
        employee[employeeCounter] = new employeeHourly();         
        employee[employeeCounter]->setVariables(empID, fName, lName, stat, 
    rate, hrs);
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateGrossPay(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateTaxAmount(); 
        employee[employeeCounter]->calculateNetPay();
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        employeeCounter++;}
}
    /*employeeCounter = 0;
    while (employeeCounter < totalEmployeeCount){
        employee[employeeCounter]->printData();
        employeeCounter++;
    }*/
system("pause");    
}
```

When I run my program in CMD, and input for 2 employees the second employee will overwrite the first one.  I am not sure what is wrong and any help or guidance would be very appreciated (I could not find this asked earlier but I assume it has been, I am a new student and not familiar with Stack Overflow).

Comment: Activate your compiler warnings, you will some issues...

Comment: would you know how i could do that on dev-c++?

Comment: You should have spent time learning how to use your debugger -- then problems like this wouldn't or shouldn't take 4 days to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `employeeCounter` and it'll work:

```
int employeeCounter = 0;
```

Frankly, this code simply is not presentable at all. You need to at least indent it consistently. There are a lot of things that you need to look at.

You should go through the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c-core-guidelines).

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md

**Edited -- Updated Code**

Here's your cleaned up and functional code:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
public:
    double salary, hourlyRate, taxRate, taxAmount, grossPay, netPay, otPay;
    int hours, otHours;

    int payStat;
    int employeeID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

public:
    void setVariables( int empID, string fName, string lName, int stat, int rate, int hrs )
    {
        employeeID = empID;
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        payStat = stat;

        if( payStat == 1 )
        {
            hourlyRate = rate;
        }
        else
        {
            salary = rate;
        }

        hours = hrs;
    }

public:
    virtual double calculateGrossPay() = 0;

    double calculateTaxAmount()
    {
        taxRate = .30;
        taxAmount = grossPay*taxRate;
        return taxAmount;
    }

    double calculateNetPay()
    {
        netPay = grossPay - taxAmount;
        return netPay;
    }

    void printData()
    {
        cout << setprecision(2) << setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint);
        cout << firstName << setw(6) << lastName << setw(6) << employeeID << setw(10) << hours << setw(3)
             << otHours << setw(8) << grossPay << setw(8) << netPay << setw(8) << otPay << endl;
    }
};

class employeeSalary : public employee
{
public:
    double calculateGrossPay()
    {
        double regPay = hours*hourlyRate;
        double hourlyRate = ((salary/52)/40);
        if (hours > 40)
        {
            otHours = (hours - 40);
            otPay = (otHours * hourlyRate);
            grossPay = (regPay + otPay);
        }
        else if (hours <= 40)
        {
            otHours = 0; otPay = 0; grossPay = regPay;
        }

        return grossPay;
    }
};

class employeeHourly : public employee
{
public:
    double calculateGrossPay()
    {
        const double regPay = (40 * hourlyRate);

        if ( hours > 40 )
        {
            otHours = (hours - 40);
            otPay = (otHours * hourlyRate * 1.5);
            grossPay = (regPay + otPay);
        }
        else
        {
            otHours = 0;
            otPay = 0;
            grossPay = regPay;
        }

        return grossPay;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int employeeCounter = 0;
    int totalEmployeeCount = 0;

    string fName, lName;
    int empID = 0, stat = 0, rate = 0, hrs = 0;

    cout << "enter # of employees you want to process:  ";
    cin >> totalEmployeeCount;

    employee* employee[100];

    while( employeeCounter < totalEmployeeCount )
    {
        cout<<"Is employee "<< employeeCounter+1 << " hourly or salary? (enter 1 for hourly / 2 for salary):";
        cin>>stat;

        if (stat == 1)
        {
            cout << "Instantiating and HOURLY employee object inherited from base class employee" << endl << endl;

            cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";
            cin>>empID;
            cout<<"Enter employee's first name: ";
            cin>>fName;
            cout<<"Enter employee's last name: ";
            cin>>lName;
            cout<<"Enter employee's hourly wage: ";
            cin>>rate;
            cout<<"Enter employee's hours for this week: ";
            cin>>hrs;

            employee[employeeCounter] = new employeeHourly();
            employee[employeeCounter]->setVariables( empID, fName, lName, stat, rate, hrs );
            employee[employeeCounter]->calculateGrossPay();
            employee[employeeCounter]->calculateTaxAmount();
            employee[employeeCounter]->calculateNetPay();
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            employeeCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"instantialting a SALARY employee object in herited from base class employee"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";
            cin>>empID;
            cout<<"Enter employee's first name: ";
            cin>>fName;
            cout<<"Enter employee's last name: ";
            cin>>lName;
            cout<<"Enter employee's hourly wage: ";
            cin>>rate;
            cout<<"Enter employee's hours for this week: ";
            cin>>hrs;
            employee[employeeCounter] = new employeeHourly();
            employee[employeeCounter]->setVariables(empID, fName, lName, stat,
                                                    rate, hrs);
            employee[employeeCounter]->calculateGrossPay();
            employee[employeeCounter]->calculateTaxAmount();
            employee[employeeCounter]->calculateNetPay();
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            employeeCounter++;
        }
    }

    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";

    for ( int i = 0; i < employeeCounter; ++i )
    {
        employee[ i ]->printData();
    }

    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";

    return 0;
}
```

You had global variables to store the data and in your print function you were printing those globals. That means you'd only get the latest stored values.

You *really* need to go through the fundamentals of OOP to get those things right.

Always indent your code.
Initialize your variables.
And, don't comment each line of code.

Comment: If i make that change it still overwrites the output, i had tried that. and this is my first post to Stack Overflow so I am not great at formatting, the majority of the code was given to the class in this manner. Sorry.

Comment: *If i make that change* -- It isn't a matter of "if you make the change".  You are using an uninitialized variable, and that is a bug in your program, so you have no choice but to fix it.

Comment: @Teluxx: I've updated my answer with the functional code. And, it really took a lot of effort to check, verify; and, then correct. You're going to pay me big time. :) Try to go through the fundamentals once again. And, practice, practice, practice!

Comment: So would it count as payback to promise i will read the fundementals, review and learn from your code?  My teacher has not been responding to my questions ( i take online courses) and I would prefer to learn and be competent rather than just get good grades. So i very,very much appreciate your assistance Azeem.

Comment: @Teluxx: Yup, that would count. :) That is what you ought to do! Best of luck! Kindly accept my answer if it helped you.